# R Shiny Leaflet - Adding Content to SidebarPanel based on click events

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on a Shiny dashboard which is taking a **shape file** from my system and using leaflet to show some categorical variable (like winning party in an election).

In the main panel, I have the map, which is colored based on winning party.

*In the sidebar panel, I want to display fields of any particular constituency which has been **clicked upon** in a particular formatting.* I can't figure out how to do this. I would also like to introduce "zoom on click" features.

[Working Dashboard - sidebarpanel on right with field to be filled which can be seen in popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCGzv.png)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT1: I was also able to pass a vector array as layerId in addPolygon function but don't know how to use the layerId to retrieve other attributes.

Comment: Are you asking SO to write code for you? Or do you have something to post with a specific question.

Comment: I could get an idea from some sample code as to how to get data when I've clicked on a map attribute.

Comment: Passed layerId to all attributes and accessed them through click events and then got layerId from event$id which I used as a key for getting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved to an extent:

I used htmloutput in ui.R. Using layerId accessed other vars and passed them through renderText in server.R